# Best 2D Plane out of 3D points

Tags: 3d, linear-regression, plane

I have the following problem: I have given some 3D Points like
(0,2,2), (0,4,5) etc..

And I want to get the **best fit Plane** through those points. It's a bit like a linear regression. The problem is, the points don't match exactly. So I have to find the best plane going through them in the 3D area. The Size of the plane doesn't matter, I just need **one Vector** out of my points.
I read a bit about regression but It didn't help me out.

I just ask for a **resource, pseudo code** or just a working code. Just something for me to start.

Comment: A vector and a plane are different things.   Which do you want?  What efforts have you taken so far?

Comment: I want to create a Plane out of the Vector. I googled literally everything about regression and this problem but I didn't find out anything helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have source code for fitting a 2D polynomial such as

Y = a + bX + cX^2

you will see that internally the code regresses Y against X^0 (1.0), X^1 (X)and X^2 to find equation parameters a, b, and c. You might also have regressed Y against other terms such as sin(X) or exp(X), the source code that performs the linear regression does not care and would happily fit those terms also.

You can use that same source code to instead determine parameters for

Z = a + bX + cY

by regressing Z against 1.0,  X^1 (X) and Y^1 (Y) to find equation parameters a, b and c. You might also regress against X^1 * Y^1 (X*Y) or even sin(X) or [log(X) * exp(Y)].

Many software packages have pre-packaged functions for fitting 2D polynomials because that fitting task is very common, but the code inside such functions can be used as I describe above - if you have source code, look through the polynomial fitting method and copy-paste-edit the code's data formatting as I describe above and you should be fine.